# import css and scss files into reactjs shows error unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

Believe me I have been combing **Stackoverflow** past question to see if any solution can solve my problem but without luck.

Here am trying to import two files into a react app(css and scss).This files resides inside **node_modules** directory.

If I import it with **@** parameter, it will display error **unknown token**

```
@import '~react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
@import '~react-toastify/dist/main.scss';
```

If I import it without **@** parameter as per code below, it will display error **Module not found. cannot resolve**

```
import '~react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
    import '~react-toastify/dist/main.scss';
```

In my webpack config. i have already set the extension resolve

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss']
    },
```

to css and scss filename but cannot get it to work

here is my full **webpack config** files.

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body'
    })],
    devServer: {
port: 4200,
        historyApiFallback: true

    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object

        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost'
        })

    }
}
```

here is **package.json** files

```
{
  "name": "importing css example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-toastify": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webpack configuration is missing a loader to load style for css or scss extenstion. As you have not specified any loader for files with CSS or SCSS extension (which ever may be your scenario), webpack by default treats it as a JS. Also make changes to the module loading rules in your webpack config as follows:

```
module:{
  rules: [
    {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-3']
            }
        },
    {
      test: /\.(s?)css$/,
      use: [
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader"
          ]
      }]
    }
```

add the above code to you webpack config and then try to load the scss or css file. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: i have added your solution to the module rules  but still receive error unexpected token with @ parameter in the import(@import) being highlighted as the cause of the error.

Comment: can you attach you css and scss files ?

Comment: This is what works for me. I implemented your solutions and then install the following  npm install --save-dev style-loader
npm install --save-dev css-loader
npm install sass-loader --save-dev
npm install node-sass